# How to add a cover photo above a table view (like path or everyme app)

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to add a cover photo above a UITableView, so that the photo appears to be in a fixed position and the UITableView scrolls over the top of it.

Both Path and EveryMe have this feature.

**Image 1: Initial Appearance**

**Image 2: Appearance when table is scrolled vertically (Note: the top of the image does not change)**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9nLu.jpg

Comment: I don't see a scrolling table view; I see only a lower 'view' moving up over the upper image view.  What is the prototype cell?  The bike image w/ 'no comments' area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that:

- The image view is placed behind the table view, so it stays in a fixed position
- The background of the table view is transparent, so the image can show through
- The table has a very tall header (or first row) that also has a transparent background
- The other cells in the table have an opaque background

Comment: A open source example can be found at https://github.com/Rheeseyb/RBParallaxTableViewController